# grep "something" anyfiles.log > afile.csv , don't need to print the input path and file name to CSV file

Tags: network-manager

I have some logs files, they have more than 30000 lines. I need to find the name "domain" and save in CSV file but after saving, any lines in CSV file has been added the path and file name of input files at the beginning of very line of CSV file. How can I do if I don't need the path and input file name add to CSV files.

Example:

```
Input
#cat /home/log/any.log

any things..domain, anything
any things..domain, anything
any things..domain, anything


grep "domain" /home/logs/any.log > newfile.csv

Output:
#cat newfile.csv
/home/logs/any.log:domain
/home/logs/any.log:domain
/home/logs/any.log:domain


#----My requirement output is:

cat newfile.csv
domain
domain
domain
```

Kind regards, please help me if anyone knowns

Answer (score 21):

Use the `--no-filename` option for grep.

> Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.

```
grep --no-filename "domain"
```

Reference: [Grep Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control)

Answer (score 1):

See `man cut` for details, but the short answer is `grep "domain" /home/logs/*.log | cut -d: -f2 >newfile.csv`.

Or see `man grep` and do `grep -o "domain" /home/logs/*.log >newfile.csv`

PS: grep does NOT output the filename if there's only ONE file on the command line, like `grep "domain" /home/logs/any.log` in your example. If you want to force filenames to be output, `grep "domain" /home/logs/any.log /dev/null` will do the trick.

Comment: `man cut`... sounds painful.